# My responsive website is not working on samsung and OPPO phones. Why?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

I have a responsive website created using HTML, CSS and Javascript. It's working very well in all devices except some old model of samsung devices like Galaxy J2 and some other OPPO mobile phones. I have a div element with background image and it should not be repeated in all screen sizes. As i mention before this also working in all devices except samsung and OPPO.

Why it is happening ? Is there anything should i added to the code in order to act like this ?

### CSS (Class name of div element containg an image as background)

```
    .about-left-w3ls {
    background: url(../images/img1.JPG)no-repeat 5px 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 794px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
     z-index: 999;
     margin: 0;
     border-radius: 10%;
     }
```

### Media Query

```
@media(max-width:991px) {

.about-left-w3ls {
    min-height: 415px;
    background: url(../images/img1.JPG)no-repeat 0px -212px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
}

@media(max-width:900px) {

.about-left-w3ls {
    background: url(../images/img1.JPG)no-repeat 0px -183px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

}

@media(max-width:768px) {

.about-left-w3ls {
    min-height: 340px;
    background: url(../images/img1.JPG)no-repeat 0px -159px;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
}

@media(max-width:568px) {

.about-left-w3ls {
    min-height: 270px;
    background: url(../images/img1.JPG)no-repeat 0px -112px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

}

@media(max-width:440px) {

.about-left-w3ls {
    min-height: 239px;
    background: url(../images/img1.JPG)no-repeat 0px -88px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

}



@media(max-width:384px) {

.about-left-w3ls {
    background: url(../images/img1.JPG)no-repeat 0px -77px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi @Siva, please include sample code or even better a Codepen link so the people can see what you have done. Include the browser version and the OS that you were testing the issue.

Comment: This lacks absolutely any kind of actually _useful_ information about the problem so far. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit the question accordingly. (And no, do not just post a link to the site - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-website-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @Renesansz i have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Are the browsers on Samsung and Oppo devices the current version? This situation is not related to devices, but rather to the versions of the browsers used. If you write the correct codes for all screen resolutions, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I have tested it on newly updated version of browser in above mentioned devices.